# Blackscreen after rtcwake triggered restart

Tags: linux, rtcwake

I use Debian Jessie und multiple computers, whenever I use rtcwake with `mem`, `disk`, or `off` the computer retarts (I can hear HDD and coolers spinning up) but only shows a blackscreen (no cursor, yet screen says it got a signal).

Neither grub or the EFI-splash is showing up. `dmesg` - or any log for that matter - doesnt't have any entries, indicating that the OS didn't resume at all.

The problem persists until I completely cut power, another restart does not fix the problem. I need an idea on how to debug this or a full solution of course.